# about semi-transparent image function in android

Tags: android, xml, image

just a question wondering when I was working on my app

let say I have image which I want to make it semi-transparent but I don't want to add about image into the app (as in create another one and add it in)

is there a way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the alpha value of the image. ( If i understood you correctly) 
If you load this Image in to a ImageView, you can set it from xml like this:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/your_image_in_res"
android:alpha="1"/>
```

where according to the developers site "alpha property of the view, as a value between 0 (completely transparent) and 1 (completely opaque). " Play with the value to get the desired effect.

If you have your image int the res/drawable folder, you can use it anywhere in your code. In xml almost all elements have the following parameter:

```
android:background="@drawable/im_your_image"
```

. You just have to set this in all places, where you want this to be your background, for the parent views background. (e.g. your MainActivitys RelativeLayout that you inflate in the onCreate funciton. You see the image is put only once in the package, but this way you can set it several times as a background.

Comment: what about if its the background image?

Comment: i have try this method but if I use it on my scroll view tag with my background image the layout for that app will be blank

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve...  Could you explain more detailed?

Comment: You see i am trying the reduce the apk total package. As i already have a same image, i was hoping that i could use back the same image to make it semi transparent so that i wont need to upload another image into the apk